# Current flowing through copper wire?

Tags: batteries, current, electromagnetic

I am a grade 12 student, working with electromagnets for a physics project. My equation requires me to measure the current of a 20-25 cm bare copper wire 18 gauge. The power supply would be an aaa battery (1.5v) and a rechargeable aaa battery (1.2v). How much current can I expect from this battery (completely new, haven't even taken it out the box)with neodymium magnets (which conduct) on both the positive terminal and the negative (**one on each side of the battery basically**). I haven't really dealt like this with anything before but I want an approx value so that I can test this equation out.

Thank you.

Edit: *The circuit would be 20-25cm long*

Comment: Why not just measure it? Anyway, it'll probably be close to the short-circuit current of the battery, which depends on a lot of factors.

Comment: do you mean that it would short-circuit?

Comment: What are the magnets for?

Comment: @jonathanjo The magnets presumably are a way to connect the wires to the battery without using a battery holder

Comment: The 1.5V aaa battery will not supply much current. A few amps, I would say. The rechargeable battery may supply 10 Amps or so. I would guess that when you complete the circuit with the rechargeable battery you will see a large  spark (much larger than with the other battery) and the wire will heat up rapidly. Getting a minor burn is not out of the question if you hold onto the wire. Suggest that you plan to avoid holding the wire after making the connection, and also, wear some kind of glasses just in case particles are ejected. Not trying to exaggerate the danger. It is not that bad.

Comment: As soon as you get a current reading, disconnect the circuit. Don't leave the rechargeable battery connected for more than a second or two.

Comment: From the answer, assuming the calculation is correct, the resistance of the wire is only 5 mOhm. That would be considered a short circuit, yes.

Comment: I had actually just made a circuit, ~26 cm and had tested it with a 1.2v battery with two neodymium magnets on the side , It got decently hot within 20-25 seconds. I am assuming that this would be long enough to measure the current. I was wearing rubber gloves and safety goggles (the wire was insulated with enamel).

Comment: does anyone know why I never saw any sparks? I just connected the wire through contact, just with the copper wire touching each end of the terminal. The battery did get hot, along with the wire but I didn't see any sparks. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe the magnets close the circuit so fast and with so little bounce that you get no sparks. If the wire gets hot, you are probably doing everything right. You did remove the enamel from the contact area, right?

Comment: Once I accidentally short-circuited an AA NiMH battery for a split second. There was a bright blue arc, and a portion of the terminal melted and disappeared. It was like an arc-welder. So I am surprised that you did not get more current from your 1.2V battery. Is it NiCd or NiMH?

Comment: Thanks for the response. My 1.2v AA battery is NiMH, 1.5v AA battery is alkaline, 1.5v AAA battery is Carbon Zinc and my 1.2v AAA battery is NiCD. And I do see sparks in between the battery and the copper wire upon contact, they are just very small compared to the ones you guys are describing. Thing is, I am expecting amps around 2-4 (or higher) so that that equation I will be using would work. And yes, there is no enamel near the contact area at all.

Comment: To measure the current using a multimeter, you would set the pointer to the   " A ---"  and then the value "10". I did this and was getting a value of 4-6 amps for 3 of the batteries except the carbon zinc one where I was getting around 2-3. It was fluctuating a decent bit.

Comment: The ammeter will GREATLY limit the current. The resistance of the shunt in the ammeter is likely much greater than the resistance of the wire or the internal resistance of the battery. So this is definitely a case where the addition of the ammeter makes a big difference to the quantity being measured.

Comment: If you have two ammeters and a CC/CV supply, you can measure the resistance of the ammeter shunt.

Comment: Basically, whether you short circuit the battery directly with the ammeter or include the piece of wire, you will get almost the exact same result. Some cheap ammeters are almost 1 Ohm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As they will always tell you: don't short batteries out, they can explode.**

- First you look up the resistivity of the wire: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) lists 18 AWG wire as having approx 20 mOhm/metre
- You have 0.25 metre, so you have 5 mOhm
- *IF* the voltage stayed at 1.5 V you'd have V/R = I, 1.5/0.005 = 300 A
- 300 A is an awful lot -- it would melt 18 AWG cable in  a few seconds, for example
- However there is no way to get 300 A out of a small battery
- The typical short-circuit behaviour of a battery is still dangerous: a high current (12 A), a very rapid (3 seconds) rise in temperature of the battery -- over boiling, perhaps 120 C and a very rapid decrease in current as the energy is used, followed by a slower decrease in temperature. (Taken from [battery manufacturer graph](https://products.varta-microbattery.com//applications/mb_data/DOCUMENTS/GRAPHS/04103/G_04103_O_S01_en.pdf) )

Measuring that would be tricky and require good safety work.

**I'd suggest it's not a suitable experiment for grade 12 without considerable supervision on safety, and indeed how to capture the measurement quickly.**

Comment: I'm betting battery stays together but distorts or ruptures.

Comment: Thanks, https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/calculating-the-final-velocity-of-a-simple-electric-train.961210/page-2   This is why I need the amps/current calculated.